# Count and hide links if 1 or less. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div set up that has dynamically loaded links.

```
<div class="module">
    <a href="#" class="sidelink">
    <a href="#" class="sidelink">
</div>
```

How can I set this up so that if their is 1 link or less in this div, to hide all (in this case the 1) link. Looking for a simple jquery solution/

Comment: precisely, if it is just 1 link hide the link right? less doesn't make any difference as there won't be anything to hide.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have many such sections you can do:

```
$('.module:not(:has("a:nth-of-type(2)"))').hide();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSWQm/)**

- [nth-of-type](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)
- [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- [has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)
- .module - selects all the module elements
- a:nth-of-type(2) - selects any anchor with the index of 2 i.e if you have more that 1 anchor
- see a has selector, it now combined above 2 exprs to select module having anchor 2 or more, but hold on
- a not selector wrapping the above 2 ensure it selects modules that doesn't satisfy the above conditions.

Inorder to hide the modules, try:

```
$('.module:not(:has(a:gt(0)))').find('a').hide();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXVsA/)

or just

```
$('.module a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).siblings('a').length == 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: nice.  And since OP mentioned hiding the link, not the whole div, you could do `$('.module:not(:has("a:nth-of-type(2)")) a').hide();`

Comment: @andi i missed that part.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

`toggle()` will hide/show based on a boolean, checking if there are more than one anchor would evaluate as true or false :

```
$('.module a').toggle($('.module a').length > 1);
```

and close the anchors.

Comment: @PSL - This works perfectly fine, the OP stated **"I have a div"**, and as long as there aren't more div's, it works great.

Comment: @adeneo oh ok, in that case my answer is an overkill, probably... So take back my comment...

Comment: @PSL - Nope, your answer is great, could be a little slow with all the non native pseudo selectors, but noone will ever notice that anyway. Also, my answer would need an each() loop to do the same, but then it would work with multiple .module's as well. We're all pretty darn great!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('.sidelink').length === 1) {
    $('.module').hide();
}
```